# Trying to combine multiple workbooks in different folders into a master one

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to pull data from multiple workbooks, and combine the data into one dataset.

I started pulling data from one, and it worked fine.
When I tried to add the 2nd workbook it's pulling the data but just writing over the first set of data.

I'll eventually be doing this 6 different times for files located in different file paths and not in the same folder.

Each work book has the same named tabs, and headers are exactly the same.

A1:AA1 are the headers. - Exactly the same on source files and master file.

I'm trying to pull the data and paste below the header on the master worksheet, and keep pasting below as i pull data from each workbook.

I'm looking for a solution to change the "31" to paste to next unused row as the 31 will change as data is entered on the source files.

wbPrior2.Sheets("wsPrior2").Range("A2:AA" & Prior2LastRow).copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wsCurrent").Cells(***31***, 1)

```
Option Explicit

Sub RectangleRoundedCorners3_Click()
    ' clear current data
    Sheets("wsCurrent").Rows("2:" & Sheets("wsCurrent").Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    ' open First File to Combine
    Dim fileNameFullPath As String
    fileNameFullPath = "C:\Filelocationpath\wbPrior.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileNameFullPath, ReadOnly:=True
    ' ----- copy file. after opening workbook, it becomes an active workbook
    Dim wbPrior As Workbook
    Set wbPrior = ActiveWorkbook
    ' --- get LastRow
    Dim PriorLastRow As Integer
    ' -- wsPrior
    PriorLastRow = wbPrior.Sheets("wsPrior").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' --- copy wsPrior to wsCurrent
    wbPrior.Sheets("wsPrior").Range("A2:AA" & PriorLastRow).copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wsCurrent").Cells(2, 1)
    ' --- close wbPrior
    wbPrior.Close
    
    'Second Source File Data Pull
    ' --- open "wbPrior2.xlsx"
    Dim fileNameFullPath2 As String
    fileNameFullPath2 = "C:\Filelocationpath2\wbPrior2.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fileNameFullPath2, ReadOnly:=True
    ' ----- copy file. after opening workbook, it becomes an active workbook
    Dim wbPrior2 As Workbook
    Set wbPrior2 = ActiveWorkbook
    ' --- get LastRow
    Dim Prior2LastRow As Integer
    ' -- wsPrior2
    Prior2LastRow = wbPrior2.Sheets("wsPrior2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' --- copy wsPrior to wsCurrent
    wbPrior2.Sheets("wsPrior2").Range("A2:AA" & Prior2LastRow).copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wsCurrent").Cells(31, 1)
    ' --- close wbPrior
    wbPrior2.Close
    
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a column that is always filled with a value (e.g. an ID-column; in the example I use column "A") then you could use `nextRow` instead of `31`.

```
dim next Row as long
nextRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wsCurrent").Cells(1,1).End(xlDown).Row +1
```

or

```
dim next Row as long
nextRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("wsCurrent").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

this would be very similar to the way you're already doing it with e.g.

```
Prior2LastRow = wbPrior2.Sheets("wsPrior2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Furthermore, if you want to avoid to hard-code all 6 files you could also use this function to sequentially pick the files.

```
Public Function f_FiledialogChooseData() As Variant
Dim fd As FileDialog
f_FiledialogChooseData= 0
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
If fd.Show = True Then
    f_FiledialogChooseData= fd.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Debug.Print "The user pressed >>cancel<<"
End If
Set fd = Nothing 
End Function
```

combined with

```
fileNameFullPath = f_FiledialogChooseData()
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you for your assistance as this solved my problem. In terms of referencing the file path I'm going to stick with that for now but may look at UNC in the future as the users have different Drive Numbers for the shared drive location. Again Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear that your problem got solved!